# How to bypass a javascript function using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I want to learn how to make a script in Greasemonkey to modify variables in a page or bypass a delaying function.

Here is the script found in the middle of the page:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    x300=100;

    function countdown() {
        x300--;
        if (x300 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
                '<strong>Proceed to URL - <a href="http://XXXX.com/11123324">click here</a>!</strong>';
        }
        if (x300 > 0) {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
                'You will be redirected in ' + x300 + ' seconds.';
            setTimeout('countdown()',100000);
        }
    }

    countdown();
</script>
```

Of course I want to do a script that will redirect me to `http://XXXX.com/11123324`,
I am still noob so the best script I made was:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        aaa
// @include     bbbb
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

x300=1;
countdown()
```

but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

Based on [the original question (now deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14876047/331508), and the apparent target page, the variable `x300` and the function `countdown()` *are* global.  But the variable name `x300` actually changes from page to page.  This means that it is not a good choice for scripting.

The function name `countdown()` appears to be constant though.  So, you can extract the desired link from the *function source* using regex:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        aaa
// @include     bbbb
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var addrFound       = false;
var cntDwnFuncSrc   = window.countdown;  // Use unsafeWindow if grant is not none.
if (cntDwnFuncSrc) {
    cntDwnFuncSrc           = countdown.toString ();
    var payloadAddrMatch    = cntDwnFuncSrc.match (/href="([^"]+?)"/);
    if (payloadAddrMatch  &&  payloadAddrMatch.length > 1) {
        location.assign (payloadAddrMatch[1]);
        addrFound           = true;
    }
}

if ( ! addrFound) {
    alert ("Payload address not found.  Site probably changed");
}
```

---

---

---

Given your sample page, **your userscript should have worked.**  That it didn't, means **you are omitting or changing a key detail in your question!**

1. **What errors do you get in the error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)?**
2. What happens when you run the following code in the Firefox or Firebug console?

   ```
   console.log (x300);
   console.log (countdown);
   ```
3. What is the URL of the target page so that we can see what is really going on?

Comment: its worked like a charm :) , thanks a lot  . I will try to understand your code and to do many tests later because I must go now . again thank you a lot )

Comment: I did a lot of tests and it worked all the time :) , I love the approach of getting the link using the regex . but I have a question , in this script you parse the function countdown (at least that what I think) so my question is , is it possbile to parse the all the page code not just the countdown function ?

Comment: Yes, you could parse all of the page's code, but that's a really poor idea in practice.  See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/331508) for *one* of the many reasons.

Comment: yeah I know its a painful process , I do a lot of html parsing using (grep and sed) and I know the risks . however sometimes its become the quickest available solution so can you tell me how to do it (what is the instruction ?) thanks for your time

Comment: That is another question. Ask a new one, **with specific details**, if necessary.  However, many variations of that question have already been asked, so search SO before posting.